# Create "reverse engineered" python wheel from a package installed via pip that is not on a package index like PyPi

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel, pip-tools

The question might sound a bit weird because creating wheels is standard Python knowledge.

We have the special situation that we have numerous different Python environments with an unversioned package `my_package` that was installed some time ago. So we have multiple installations of this package with different underlying code bases.

Now the problem is that we want to re-use this package in another project. Thus, my idea was to create a "reverse engineered" wheel.

Let's say I have:

```
$ pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
aiohttp                            3.7.4.post0
my_package                         0.0.1
alembic                            1.7.1
```

and want to create a wheel from `my_package` and possibly the other packages in the environment.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If it was installed with `pip install`, isn't it easier to just grab the wheel from pip's cache dir?

Comment: Is this also possible if it was not installed via a wheel file but from sources?

Comment: The only thing that matters here is the installation command that was used. Which one was used? Apart from that, `find ~/.cache/pip -type f -name '*.whl'` (or similar on windows/macOS) should be an easy check regardless.